# Pear Excel Writer: trimming leading zeros - how to prevent?

Tags: php, excel, pear, export-to-excel

I'm using the [Pear Excel Writer](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer) package to export a dataset to Excel from PHP. My problem is some of the data fields have leading zeros (such as a zip code), but these are being trimmed in Excel. I tried adding an apostrophe to the start of the fields to force a text field, but then Excel displays it, which I don't want. I'm neither a PHP nor Excel expert, but I expect I'm missing something relatively simple.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's more excel problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to display leading zeros in excel, you have to [apply a custom number format](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/81518). for fixed-length numbers - your case - this would be something like `00000` (for a 5 digit number), for variable-length numbers something like `"000"#` (a number with 3 leading zeros). this excel format should be taken over by `Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer`. if not, you could set it from within the writer with [`Format::setNumFormat`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.spreadsheet-excel-writer-format.setnumformat.php).

Comment: I don't always find the Pear documentation as clear as it could be, but through trial and error playing with the setNumFormat I was able to fix it.